# Basis of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with this exercise. 
It is the first time that I see an exercise like this and I don't know where to start.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Consider the following vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ :

$$ W = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x_1 + x_3 = 0, x_2 + x_4 = x_1 \} $$

How many bases for $W$ can you find?

Comment: "*How many bases of $W$ can you find?*"  Every infinite vector space of nonzero dimension has infinitely many bases, including your example.  If you are looking to find an example of a basis, you can set $x_1$ and $x_2$ as free variables, lets call them $s$ and $t$.  Given a specific choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$, this will imply that the value of $x_3$ and $x_4$ must be in terms of $s$ and $t$.  So, we have ourselves any solution to the system can be written as a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ where all entries are written in terms of $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical vector in that subspace looks like $\langle x_1,x_2,-x_1,x_1-x_2\rangle$. Since this depends only on the two coordinates $x_1, x^2$, this is a two dimensional subspace. There are uncountably many basis you can find. For example here is the basis corresponding to $x_1 = x_2 = 1$:

$$\left\{\;\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}\;\right\}$$

But then, for any choice of $a,b \in \mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\}$, this is also a basis:

$$\left\{\;\begin{bmatrix}a\\0\\-a\\a\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\b\\0\\-b\end{bmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that all the elements depend on the two coordinates x1,x2. But I am missing the point when you generate the basis. I don't understand how you pick the elements of the two vectors

Comment: Any nonzero choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$ will generated that subspace. I just let them both equal $1$ and then plugged those in the typical vector $\langle x_1,x_2,-x_1,x_1-x_2\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

Find one basis for $W$, let it be $\{b_1, b_2\}$. Now show that $\{\lambda b_1, \lambda b_2\}$ is also a basis for $W$, for every nonzero $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, there exists uncountably many bases for $W$.